# How to get the meta tags values from website in javascript Ajax

Tags: ajax

I want get the meta tags values from website in java script Ajax
Please see the below code:

How will i get meta tags from the response. and i am not getting response by using getJSON.

Comment: The "below code" is non-existent. Why would you use `getJSON` if you want to read *meta tags* which are something you find in **HTML** not JSON!

Answer (score 1):

Simple just use jQuery like this:

**HTML Code using (jQuery load method):**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () { 
        // pass param url
        var data = 'url=' + 'http://neerajsingh.blog.com/category/java-script/';
        // load meta tag viewport in div
        $("#content").load('process.php ', data, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "success") {                
                // function with response data
                var viewport = $(response).filter('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content");             
                $("#content").html(viewport);
            }
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**PHP Code (process.php)**

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
echo $homepage;
?>
```

**Via Ajax:**

```
$(function () {
    // pass param url
    var data = 'url=' + 'http://neerajsingh.blog.com/category/java-script/';
    // using ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : 'process.php',
        data : data,
        type : 'GET',
        success : function (response) {
            // function with response data
            var viewport = $(response).filter('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content");
            // show meta tag value
            $("#content").html(viewport);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The question is asking about Ajax, not the current document.